# Is it possible to rename a path componet of files in Cloud Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage using the Firebase SDKs.
I'm making a similar app with 'yelp'.

I wonder when a store name is changed if storage's object name could be changed.

My structure is like this.

```
[bucket]
+ [store name1]
    + pic1
    + pic2
+ [store name2]
    + pic1
...
```

---

**EDIT**

### client

I want to change the cafe, starbucks's name.
So, send a request to a server to change the cafe's name to starbee.

### Storage

Each of objects name is same as cafe's name.
so the structure is like below.

```
[bucket]
+ [starbucks]
    + picture 1
    + picture 2
```

My problem is that even though I already changed cafe(starbucks)'s name to starbee, the starbucks object in my bucket still remain its name cause I didn't send any request to my storage.

So, my question is how to handle this situation. I have no idea how to send a request to change the name of object in storage.
Also, what am I suppose to do for the correct storage structure?

Comment: Could you edit the question to explain in more detail?  Your second paragraph is confusing to me. Showing code usually helps.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added more detail. I'm not sure if code could make you understand my situation better, and it's not code issue in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rename a path component in Cloud Storage like you would in a typical desktop computer filesystem, as there are actually no "folders" present.  What you would have to do is iterate and rename each individual file under that path component to match what you want.

Comment: Yeah exactly, so my question was if there's no way then how to handle this issue every time user want to change the name? because storage object name follows the object's name in db. I mean, when to save files into the storage, should I name the object's name in bucket as id number?

Comment: You might want a random immutable ID for this that is not the display name that the user chooses.

Comment: I'm afraid of that way cause another issue like because of a name as ID, access to data would be difficult. Whenever I want to access data, I should know the ID value. To know the ID, I have to make a request again. Do I miss anything about this?

Comment: No, you know what you need to do.